# Is commit needed after resolving merge conflict during Git rebase?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-rebase

I rebase another branch onto my checkout branch and I get a conflict during rebase. i resolved the merge conflict.

```
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto 77c951b
You are currently rebasing branch 'test' on '77c951b'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   br_boss_buha_faktura/forms/br_boss_buha_faktura_head_dtl.frm
        modified:   br_boss_buha_faktura/valuelists/br_boss_buha_faktura_client.val
        new file:   br_boss_buha_faktura/valuelists/br_boss_buha_faktura_client_name.val

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   br_boss_buha_faktura/valuelists/br_boss_buha_faktura_client.val
```

Do I need to commit the above resolved merge conflict `git commit` or can I directly go further using `git rebase --continue`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some good answers here but to answer the question. **NO** you do not *need* to commit after resolving the merge conflict.

Once you have added the resolution to the git staging area via `git add <file>` a `git rebase --continue` will *make the commit for you using the original commit message*.

**NOTE** the commit hash will change! So when you go to merge this into another branch that has commits that you altered in your branch you will have issues merging those branches together.

---

**NOTE** I said you do not *need* to `git commit` after resolving a `git rebase` conflict, but you *can* if you want to.

It may be useful to split files from one commit into a series of individual commits if it makes more sense. Usually you just want to resolve the conflict though. As is shown here: [Break a previous commit into multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits).

Comment: So you don't _need to_. Okay. It would be nice if your answer also explained what would happen if you _did_ commit before continuing the rebase.

Answer (score 4):

Here I see

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   br_boss_buha_faktura/valuelists/br_boss_buha_faktura_client.val
```

Please do

```
git add br_boss_buha_faktura/valuelists/br_boss_buha_faktura_client.val
```

Then

```
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: After `git add`, is `git commit -a` is really needed?

Comment: Yeah please do git commit -a

Comment: Could you please explain, why I need to do a commit, because I found a [thread here, which explains the opposite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3611293/183704)?

Comment: How many commits you have in your topic_branch matters.
Let's say you have a single commit then you can resolve the conflicts and do git add and git commit.If there are more than 1 commits then you should do a git rebase --continue . Even if you have a single commit you can do git rebase --continue(safer)

Comment: This does not really answer my question.

Comment: Please let me know how was your repo before you started the rebase.
Let me presume you had made some changes to some files and had done  a commit for the same. Later when you tried to rebase you got conflicts. So the solution would be to resolve the conflicts and add them to notify that the conflicts has been resolved and followed by it do git rebase --continue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62166/discussion-between-pala-and-buzz-dee).

Comment: I would never advise use of the `-a` option, especially not to `git commit`: It is basically asking for mistakes to happen ("Oh, you just published all your '.o' files - looks like a very smart thing to do..."). Better use `git status` and add what you really want to add.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `git rebase --continue` will rewrite the current commit you are applying to the form you changed it to. It will commit the changes under the same name you had in the `test` branch.

Note you are rebasing on a commit, might be a detached HEAD state! Usually, one rebases on `master` or a `staging` branch.

Comment: So I do not need to use `git commit`? I fix it and then I just use `git rebase --continue`? What do you mean with "Usually, one rebases on master or a staging branch."? I'm on branch `test` and have done a `git rebase featureA` onto the `test`branch.

Comment: Yes, just as [the documentation tells you to](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). Also, as @pala said, you have one file that is not staged to commit. Is that the intention or should it be part of the current rebase commit?

Comment: Yes, I figured out, that I have to add the file `git add br_boss_buha_faktura/valuelists/br_boss_buha_faktura_client.val`, because `git rebase --continue` does not work and I get the message `You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add`.

Answer (score 1):

If you DO commit your changes, I believe that you can do a `git rebase --skip` to skip over the now non-existent merge conflict.